# Video.js playing Quicktime mov file

Tags: html, video.js

I'm trying to play a Quicktime .mov file (wrapping an H264 video) in a browser using video.js. I've created a new Typescript project in Visual Studio 2012 and referenced the video file in a very simple html file adapted from the demo file downloaded from http://www.videojs.com/.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Video.js | HTML5 Video Player</title>
  <link href="video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="video.js"></script>
  <script>
    videojs.options.flash.swf = "video-js.swf";
  </script>      
</head>
<body>

  <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="640" height="264"
      data-setup="{}">
    <source src="media/somevideo.mov" type='video/mp4' />
  </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately this doesn't appear to play in either Chrome or IE (I haven't tried other browsers). I've tried changing the type to type='video/quicktime' with no luck, and I've tried to remove the type attribute all together. In the former case the video 'loads' forever. In the second scenario, text appears at the top of the video object telling the used to download the latest version of Flash.

I've got a feeling this may be a MIME-type issue, but am not sure how to fix it. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Steve

EDIT I'm going to give up on this. I've decided I can batch convert to H264 and create some metadata to extract the extra information I need. This makes life much easier that relying on video.js interacting with QT.

Comment: Does it work in Safari?

Answer (score 3):

Different devices (and browsers) require different video formats. In the past, I've managed to get full support by using [this service](http://zencoder.com/en/). However, you might be able to do it yourself with ffmpeg.

As you can see from the html source at videojs, multiple video file formats are included.

```
<video id="home_video" controls preload="none" poster="/img/poster.jpg" class="video-js vjs-default-skin">
    <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm" type="video/webm">
    <track kind="captions" src="/vtt/captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English"></track>
</video>
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I can't change the format from a Quicktime wrapped H264 file as it's for a rather specific internal tool. I've gone the Video.js route in order for code-reuse from another project.

Comment: You are being prevented from encoding it the file into multiple formats? That's not really a technical issue. If you want to have it play properly on multiple browsers, you're going to have to serve up multiple file formats. Use ffmpeg if the video can't be transferred to a third party service.

Comment: No need for multiple browsers actually. Just needs to work on Chrome or IE9+. I was under the impression video.js would resort to QT plugin where available and necessary.

Comment: So, in chrome inspector, are you getting a 200 response from the video link? What happens if you copy that link into the browser address bar?